# Delete struct from array of structs if struct string element is nil or empty swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, struct

Lets say I have a simple struct as such:

```
struct Model: Codable {
     var myVariable: String
     var myVariable2: String?
}
```

And lets say sometimes, myVariable2 is ether a nil/null value ( from json) or a literal empty string as such "".

How would I filter out the empty nil/null and remove that particular struct from the array of structs?

I have tried:

```
Model.compactMap{ $0.myVaraible2 }.flatMap { $0 }
```

to filter out the specific string. But obviously I don't get my desired result because It's wrong. so, to first filter out the nil/empty value and then remove that struct from the array, it should be pretty straight forward yes?

Can I filter it out right after I call JSONDecoder?

```
let model = try JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)
```

something like :  I know this next line of code isn't good. =)

```
for element in model {
    if element.myVariable2.isEmpty || element.myVariable2 == "" { 
    model.remove(at: what to put here ? )
}
```

I know the for loop is BAD !!! but how would I fix it or do something more swifty ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The tool you want is `filter`:

```
let filteredModels = model.filter { $0.myVariable2 != nil }
```

This removes all elements which have a nil for this property. The property is still Optional, however, since you defined it that way. If you also want to check for `""` you can add that to the predicate:

```
let filteredModels = model.filter { $0.myVariable2 != nil && $0.myVariable2 != "" }
```

Comment: Ahh..thank you! your answer leads me to ask this: Should that specific property be Optional ?

Comment: I like mikalooch's use of `isEmpty` though. How about `$0.myVariable2?.isEmpty == false`?

Comment: I am not a fan of things that lead to `== false`. I used to use it in the early days of Swift and it's over-clever IMO. You've got to puzzle out when it's true and when it isn't. Led to a few annoying bugs for me.

Comment: When do you switch from && to `contains`?

Comment: `!["", nil].contains($0.myVariable2)` isn't bad, but I probably wouldn't use it here. An important fact is that this code should exist in exactly one place (decoding logic). If you find yourself checking "nil or empty" often, then probably you have a type problem, not a syntax problem. (You don't mean Optional if it's the same as empty; just use empty.) Since this code exists in only one place, there's no strong pressure to make it terse.